# Understanding least common generalization (or anti-unification) of types

Tags: type-theory, type-inference

I am learning how to extend a basic Hindley-Milner type system to support overloaded variables by following [Geoffrey Seward Smith's dissertation](https://users.cs.fiu.edu/%7Esmithg/papers/thesis91.pdf).

The proposed type inference algorithm makes use of the "least common generalization" (or LCG) of an overloaded variables types and cites [this Reynolds paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/jcr/ftp/transysalg.pdf) as providing an algorithm for computing the LCG.
I understand the logical concept of "least common generalization" but I am struggling to understand the mechanics of Reynolds algorithm for computing it.

My understanding is that Reynolds shows that a "least common generalization" can be found via "anti-unification". Below is a screenshot of the anti-unification algorithm described in the Reynolds paper.

[image]

I will describe my understanding of this algorithm in the context of types and highlight a few places where I have questions.

- The sequence $Z_1, Z_2, ...$ can be thought of as a infinite generator of "fresh" type vars.
- When Reynolds says "Set the variables $\overline{A}$ to $A$" and then later "let $k$ be te first symbol position at which $\overline{A}$..." does this suggest (in the context of types) that $\overline{A}$ is the sequence of free type vars in the type $A$? Or perhaps the entire type $A$ represented as an AST?
- I don't understand step (d).
- I understand that that step (e) can be thought of as replacing the parts of the types that differ with a type variable, however I don't fully understand what "beginning in the kth position" means. Does it mean some kind of sub-tree replacement in the AST that defines the type?

Is there a more appropriate resource for understanding LCG and/or anti-unification with respect to types?